# Always show FooterTemplate, even no data

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datatemplate, visible, data-controls

Is there a short way to make a FooterTemplate (in a GridView) always visible, even when DataSource is empty?

Comment: Why you want to acheive this?

Comment: Please take a look at what i commented to below, I explained what I need it for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want it to always display, regardless of content, can't you just put the footer html outside the `GridView`, instead of in the `FooterTemplate`?

If that's not an option for some reason, then you can either [add an null row to your data source if it's empty](http://weblogs.asp.net/bradygaster/archive/2006/10/24/Empty-GridView_2C00_-Invisible-Footer.aspx), or [subclass the `GridView` & override the default behaviour](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/07/how_to_show_header_and_footer.html).

Those are the only options I'm aware of (although its been a while since the last time I used a `GridView`).

Comment: I don't really care doing it with with Html, the problem is I want the columns to fit the width of the GridView columns.
I want it to show some summarization when data exist, and a insert item (which i implemented in the footer, know what i mean?) when button "New" is pressed on the item template, or show the footer always.
in other words:
*is there a way to evoke showing the footer (when no data)?
*what is actually this null data row thing, didn't getcha (im using EntityDataSource, i think will be more complicated or impossible at all).
Thanks buddy.

Comment: I don't want to use an empty row, I don't mind subclassing the GridView but no dummy data. 've u got somtn'?

Comment: The 2nd link I included (http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/07/how%5Fto%5Fshow%5Fheader%5Fand%5Ffooter.html) has some example code to allow you to have a grid with a ShowFooterWhenEmpty property.

Answer (score 7):

I was having trouble with this as well. The link from Alconja helps a lot (Thanks Alconja) but GridView.FooterRow then returns null. I need it for inserting new records from the footer.

This is my final solution that works. Now you can insert data from the footer even if the grid is empty.

**GridViewExtended.cs** (a class in the App_Code folder):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace YourNamespace
{

  public class GridViewExtended : GridView
  {
    #region Public Properties
    [Category("Behavior")]
    [Themeable(true)]
    [Bindable(BindableSupport.No)]
    public bool ShowFooterWhenEmpty
    {
      get
      {
        if (this.ViewState["ShowFooterWhenEmpty"] == null)
        {
          this.ViewState["ShowFooterWhenEmpty"] = false;
        }

        return (bool)this.ViewState["ShowFooterWhenEmpty"];
      }
      set
      {
        this.ViewState["ShowFooterWhenEmpty"] = value;
      }
    }
    #endregion

    private GridViewRow _footerRow2;
    public override GridViewRow FooterRow
    {
      get
      {
        GridViewRow f = base.FooterRow;
        if (f != null)
          return f;
        else
          return _footerRow2;
      }
    }

    protected override int CreateChildControls(System.Collections.IEnumerable dataSource, bool dataBinding)
    {
      int rows = base.CreateChildControls(dataSource, dataBinding);

      //  no data rows created, create empty table if enabled
      if (rows == 0 && (this.ShowFooterWhenEmpty))
      {
        //  create the table
        Table table = this.CreateChildTable();

        DataControlField[] fields;
        if (this.AutoGenerateColumns)
        {
          PagedDataSource source = new PagedDataSource();
          source.DataSource = dataSource;

          System.Collections.ICollection autoGeneratedColumns = this.CreateColumns(source, true);
          fields = new DataControlField[autoGeneratedColumns.Count];
          autoGeneratedColumns.CopyTo(fields, 0);
        }
        else
        {
          fields = new DataControlField[this.Columns.Count];
          this.Columns.CopyTo(fields, 0);
        }

        if (this.ShowHeaderWhenEmpty)
        {
          //  create a new header row
          GridViewRow headerRow = base.CreateRow(-1, -1, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);
          this.InitializeRow(headerRow, fields);

          //  add the header row to the table
          table.Rows.Add(headerRow);
        }

        //  create the empty row
        GridViewRow emptyRow = new GridViewRow(-1, -1, DataControlRowType.EmptyDataRow, DataControlRowState.Normal);
        TableCell cell = new TableCell();
        cell.ColumnSpan = fields.Length;
        cell.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);

        //  respect the precedence order if both EmptyDataTemplate
        //  and EmptyDataText are both supplied ...
        if (this.EmptyDataTemplate != null)
        {
          this.EmptyDataTemplate.InstantiateIn(cell);
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.EmptyDataText))
        {
          cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(EmptyDataText));
        }

        emptyRow.Cells.Add(cell);
        table.Rows.Add(emptyRow);

        if (this.ShowFooterWhenEmpty)
        {
          //  create footer row
          _footerRow2 = base.CreateRow(-1, -1, DataControlRowType.Footer, DataControlRowState.Normal);
          this.InitializeRow(_footerRow2, fields);

          //  add the footer to the table
          table.Rows.Add(_footerRow2);
        }

        this.Controls.Clear();
        this.Controls.Add(table);
      }

      return rows;
    }
  }

}
```

In the **aspx** page, simply add

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="YourPrefix" Namespace="YourNamespace" %>
```

and replace `<asp:GridView` with `<YourPrefix:GridViewExtended`

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: I tried this because I had a gridview with a footer with the option of adding a new record. 

Users would have to click on an "Add New" button in the footer after which they would see controls to add a new row.  This code does not work as expected (You would probably have to replace the call to base.CreateChildControls with code and set the id's etc).

Comment: The problem for me with this solution is that the RowDataBound event does not fire for the footer for some reason when the grid is empty. Since I need to populate some dropdowns there, this is a fatal flaw.

Comment: This is great! Thanks!

Comment: ShowFooterWhenEmpty="True"

Answer (score 3):

As one of the previous commenters mentioned, the RowDataBound event doesn't fire for the footer. I found another code snippet that [addresses this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437581/show-gridview-footer-on-empty-grid), but in addition to displaying the footer, it explicitly creates the row (firing the RowCreated event) and binds it (firing the RowDataBound event).

I've converted the above referenced code to c# using a code converter and made a few minor tweaks. I also included the comments I made as I stepped through the code to break it down. The RowCreated and RowDataBound events are firing now and I'm able to populate dropdowns in footers.

```
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.ComponentModel;

    namespace WebUI.Controls
    {
        //modified from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437581/show-gridview-footer-on-empty-grid
        public class GridViewExtended : GridView
        {

            private GridViewRow _footerRow;
            [DefaultValue(false), Category("Appearance"), Description("Include the footer when the table is empty")]
            public bool ShowFooterWhenEmpty { get; set; }

            [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden), Browsable(false)]
            public override GridViewRow FooterRow {
                get {
                    if ((this._footerRow == null)) {
                        this.EnsureChildControls();
                    }
                    return this._footerRow;
                }
            }

            protected override int CreateChildControls(System.Collections.IEnumerable dataSource, bool dataBinding)
            {
                //creates all the rows that would normally be created when instantiating the grid
                int returnVal = base.CreateChildControls(dataSource, dataBinding);
                //if no rows were created (i.e. returnVal == 0), and we need to show the footer row, then we need to create and bind the footer row.
                if (returnVal == 0 && this.ShowFooterWhenEmpty) {
                    Table table = this.Controls.OfType<Table>().First<Table>();
                    DataControlField[] dcf = new DataControlField[this.Columns.Count];
                    this.Columns.CopyTo(dcf, 0);
                    //creates the footer row
                    this._footerRow = this.CreateRow(-1, -1, DataControlRowType.Footer, DataControlRowState.Normal, dataBinding, null, dcf, table.Rows, null);
                    if (!this.ShowFooter) {
                        _footerRow.Visible = false;
                    }
                }
                return returnVal;
            }

            private GridViewRow CreateRow(int rowIndex, int dataSourceIndex, DataControlRowType rowType, DataControlRowState rowState, bool dataBind, object dataItem, DataControlField[] fields, TableRowCollection rows, PagedDataSource pagedDataSource)
            {
                GridViewRow row = this.CreateRow(rowIndex, dataSourceIndex, rowType, rowState);
                GridViewRowEventArgs e = new GridViewRowEventArgs(row);
                if ((rowType != DataControlRowType.Pager)) {
                    this.InitializeRow(row, fields);
                } else {
                    this.InitializePager(row, fields.Length, pagedDataSource);
                }
                //if the row has data, sets the data item
                if (dataBind) {
                    row.DataItem = dataItem;
                }
                //Raises the RowCreated event
                this.OnRowCreated(e);
                //adds the row to the gridview's row collection
                rows.Add(row);
                //explicitly binds the data item to the row, including the footer row and raises the RowDataBound event.
                if (dataBind) {
                    row.DataBind();
                    this.OnRowDataBound(e);
                    row.DataItem = null;
                }
                return row;
            }

        }

    }
```