# Asp.net the gridView does not show the row headers

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this problem,
        when the table is empty, the GridView does not show the row headers
        i use .net framework 4 and internet Explorer,Can you help me?
        this is the code:

```
 this is code   
     private void loadTCOR27()
             {
                 SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                 try
                 {
                     string sql = null;
                     gridViewTCOR27.Visible = true;
                     table1.Visible = false;
                     string connectionString = SestanteWeb.Global.rCRVigServer.leggiStringaConnessioneSicurezzaSqlClient();
                     sql = "select * FROM [PUMA2_FINANZIARIAFAMILIARE].[dbo].[TCOR27]";
                     SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                     connection.Open();
                     SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                     adapter.SelectCommand = command;
                     adapter.Fill(ds);
                     adapter.Dispose();
                     command.Dispose();
                     connection.Close();
                     // gridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                     gridViewTCOR27.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                     gridViewTCOR27.DataBind();

                 }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {


                 }
                 finally
                 {
                     adapter.Dispose();

                 }
             }
```

Comment: First off, you're swallowing the exception. Comment out the try/catch/finally blocks and close your adapter manually. Then see if it throws an error.

Comment: Maybe the problem is not in the GridView, but in the code. You have an empty `catch` block, so if there is  an error you will not see it.

Comment: @IrishChieftain it seems we think alike ;)

Comment: You're disposing of the adapter (twice), command and connection objects in your try block?

Answer (score 2):

Set the property `ShowHeaderWhenEmpty` to `true` in your Gridview declaration. May be it will help you.

Here is the reference to this property.
[Ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.showheaderwhenempty(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: thanks, but the problem persists because I do not see the
footer, so I can not add new records

Comment: There is also a similar property for the footer too named `ShowFooter`.Also make that to true.

Comment: @MrTony78 "the problem persists because I do not see the footer, so I can not add new records" hmm, this sounds like a different problem to me. If you can't see the footer, and/or you can't add new records, then trivially that's not the same as not being able to see the header.

Comment: sorry but I thought that showing the header also showed the footer

Comment: solved:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437581/show-gridview-footer-on-empty-grid